# Which technique for training should I use for the following dataset?

Tags: python-3.x, deep-learning, nlp, artificial-intelligence

I have a dataset which is a csv having 2 columns "Text", "Name".

"Text" column contains the news article.

"Name" column contains the extracted name from the corresponding text.

I have to train the model on this dataset, dataset contains 4000 plus unique news, where in, once your model is trained and validated, User should be able to pass any text and it should fetch the proper name.

What technique should I use and implement it. Please suggest.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are looking to search for an item by keywords. In a basic case you could use a **bag of words** approach, in which you **tokenise** the words in the Text-field and index each document accordingly.

The relevance of each document can then be calculated given some measure (for instance **cosine similarity**).

You can find an example using the genesis-library here: https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/tut3.html 
It is quite basic, note however that it does use **LSI**.